# Cannot find name of my network interface card on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, ubuntu, networkmanager

I Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop OS running on Raspberry Pi 4. I have connected a printer to the Pi's ethernet port, and I have troubles in assigning a static IP using netplan. The problem is I cannot find the name of the interface card. Right now I have created a static IP using Network Manager and with the below command I can see that it is on eth0 with IP `192.168.123.101`. The problem is I can't find the interface card name.

```
hd2900@hd2900:~$ ip add show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e4:5f:01:49:85:7f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.123.101/24 brd 192.168.123.255 scope global noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e4:5f:01:49:85:80 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.94/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlan0
       valid_lft 50472sec preferred_lft 50472sec
    inet6 fe80::5d0a:3259:a2fc:a0d4/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

In `/etc/netplan/0-rpi-ethernet-eth0.yaml` I have this content, and I suspect that `driver bcmgenet smsc95xx and lan78xx` is causing the problem.

```
hd2900@hd2900:/etc/netplan$ cat 10-rpi-ethernet-eth0.yaml 
    network:
      ethernets:
        eth0:
          # Rename the built-in ethernet device to "eth0"
          match:
            driver: bcmgenet smsc95xx lan78xx
          set-name: eth0
          dhcp4: true
          optional: true
```

To set up a static IP address I need to edit `/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml` and I need to know the name of the network interface card.

```
hd2900@hd2900:/etc/netplan$ cat 01-network-manager-all.yaml 
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

Comment: isn't it `eth0` ?

Comment: Just outta' curiosity: Why don't you ask this question on Ubuntu SE?